# How can place Firefox’s tab close buttons on the left?

Tags: firefox

I would like to make Firefox fit more to the Ubuntu default themes Ambiance and Radiance. Therefore I would like to place the tab close buttons on the left instead of the right of each tab.

I found [this tutorial](http://minu.me/-left-tab-close), but it seems to be only for Firefox 4. Is there any way of doing that for Firefox 3.6?

Comment: I just middle click each tab to close it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Install [image]**[Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122/)** Firefox Add-on
- After you install it goto Tools>>Add-ons>>Extensions>>Tab Mix Plus>>
  Preferences
  [image]
- In Display select Tab and under **Show on Tab** check **Place on left side** and click ok.
  [image]