# How can I place Gedit's tab close buttons on the left?

Tags: gedit, window-buttons, tabs

I would like to make Gedit fit more to the Ubuntu default themes Ambiance and Radiance. Therefore I would like to place the tab close buttons on the left instead of the right of each tab.

I asked [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18739/how-can-place-firefoxs-tab-close-buttons-on-the-left) about Firefox, but the best answer was adding an extension. So what can I do for Gedit ?

Besides, I bet I will shortly ask equivalent questions for Nautilus, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During [the Ayatana discussion in this bug report](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/532633?comments=all), tab placement inconsistency in the design was mentioned 115 times, in over 20 separate posts, throughout the near-800 comments, but the final decision was still to move window buttons to the left.

If you desire consistency, you're far better moving the window buttons back to the right using one of the many methods described in that bug report.  For example, use `gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string ":minimize,maximize,close"` or add the PPA outlined [in comment 792](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/532633/comments/792).

However, you've already fixed Firefox with a plug-in, and hopefully someone can help you hack Gedit.  That leaves the list of "to-do", for me personally, at :

Nautilus, Pidgin/Empathy, Thunderbird, Chromium and Eclipse

Bottom line, re-designing all these apps will take time.  I doubt the work will be complete for Natty, but perhaps we'll start to see some consistency by Natty+1.

I realise that this "answer" isn't going to help you.  I raise it simply to make you aware of the scope of the task you've undertaken here.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Tweak can handle the position of the titlebar buttons. Nevertheless, the close icon for the tabs in gedit seems not to be affected directly by the changes made by the window titlebar buttons layout.

However, Here I place a screenshot for you to find a tip on how to change the orientation of these buttons in all the applications (including firefox, nautilus, etc.)

Good luck in your quest!

Here is the screenshot:
[image]